# std::ostream ignores hex flag set on the underlying via setf()

Tags: c++, g++, iostream, iomanip

The following C++ code surprisingly produces decimal output, apparently ignoring the call to `setf()` and printing `true 42`. Using `std::setiosflags()` Gives the same result. However using `std::cout << std::hex` does give the expected output `true 0x2a`, hence `std::ios::showbase` and `std::ios::boolalpha` are being honored.

I've tested both G++ 5.4 on Ubuntu and G++ 7.2.1 on CentOS. What am I missing here?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

    std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex | std::ios::showbase | std::ios::boolalpha);
    // Uncommenting the line below doesn't make a difference.
    //std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::hex | std::ios::showbase | std::ios::boolalpha);
    // Uncommenting this line does give the desired hex output.
    //std::cout << std::hex;

    int m = 42;
    std::cout << true << ' ' << m << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant of [`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) only *adds* flags, but you need to clear the base field.

So you need to use the overload with a mask:

```
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex | std::ios::showbase | std::ios::boolalpha,
                   std::ios_base::basefield | std::ios::showbase | std::ios::boolalpha);
```

Outputs:

> true 0x2a

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c717b695c38fd158)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can clear all fields so the resulting flags would be exactly those I set?

Comment: Make a mask with everything you set and use the provided masks like `basefield`, `adjustfield`, `floatfield` etc for the flags that they include. It's aslo helpful if you look at the corresponding output manipulators like `std::hex` and see what they do - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex